# One php session variable causing unsetting session on redirect

Tags: php, mysql, session, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using a combination of Javascript and PHP Facebook sdk to integrate the log in to my website (hosted on localhost).

The code after Facebook initialization and getting the access token:

```
if(fbidExists($profile['id']) == true)
  {

    $query = "SELECT userid AS id, username FROM users WHERE fbid = ".   $profile['id'] ;

    $login = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $query));

    $_SESSION['id'] = $login['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $login['username'];

    header("Location: http:\\\\localhost\website\\");
    exit();
  }
```

**Problem:** 
 After redirect there are no session variables whenever I use `$login['username']`, otherwise the session variables are transferring.

If I change the SQL query and replace `username` by any other column there is no problem and I can see the session variables after redirect. For example :
`$query = "SELECT userid AS id, email FROM users WHERE fbid = ".   $profile['id'] ; $_SESSION['username'] = $profile['email']` creates no problem

The `$_SESSION['username']` variable can be easily set through other files and creates no problem (when i use it with my own log in)

`username` in MySQL is of `varchar` type and I am using `session_start()` on every page and `exit()` after header.

Comment: Are you getting an error? You can also `var_dump($_SESSION)`, that will tell you more...

Comment: And why the \, URLs use `/`.

Comment: You are also wide **open** to `SQL injections`! Please make sure you use prepared statements.

Comment: No i am not getting any errors, var_dump on this page returns username but when i redirect empty array...

Comment: i changed the code to:
        $query = $GLOBALS['connection']->prepare("SELECT userid AS id, username FROM users WHERE fbid = ?  UNION SELECT customerid AS id, cusername AS username FROM customers WHERE cfbid = ? ");
        $query->bind_param('ii', $profile['id'], $profile['id']);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();
        $login = $result->fetch_assoc();

I still get **null** array in var_dump after **redirect**

Comment: Also, in one of the 'else' statement I am generating a username and (then inserting it to sql), and giving that value to the session variable and i am still getting null on redirect.

Comment: First of all, send a valid Location header - proper URLs don’t contain backslashes. And then, check if the session id stayed the same, or if you got a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.
Turns out it was a problem because in the second script one on the variables was not set which was destroying the session.